# Weird Behaviour in IE 10 with Symfony2 When Using $em->remove()

Tags: php, symfony, internet-explorer-10

I try to assign a value and afterwards remove the entity from database as follow in symfony2

```php
$entity = $em->getRepository('TBundle:Test')->findOneById($id);
if ($entity) {
    $name = $entity->getName();
    $em->remove($entity);
    $em->flush();
}
```

When I pass `$name` to twig template as follow it is empty in the template when using Internet Explorer 10 downward. With Firefox, Chrome and IE 11 this problem does not exist.

```php
$template = 'TBundle:Test:show.html.twig';
return $this->render($template, array('name' => $name));
```

I would appreciate if somebody could share their experience on this.

Comment: This sounds more like an HTML issue. Try looking at the generated HTML page source and see if the relevant code is there.

Comment: You should study client/server architecture. Your browser doesn't handle the PHP the server does. So as @Mike said it is most probably an HTML/CSS problem we need to take a look at the actual page if that's possible. It could also be an JS/AJAX problem but given your return statement I don't think you are calling the function asynchronously.

Comment: I don't think this is an HTML problem. What I go in my template is very simple HTML Tags and <p>{{ name }}</p>. What I have found out is that when I remove $em->flush(); then it works well. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: How does a server-side code line influence a client-side browser? Post more code...

Comment: That is actually what I am also looking for.

Comment: Somewhere else I have a smiliar problem with $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR); where this leads to not being able to get a previously assined value for $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR); in twig template

Comment: The actual function above is called via a return $this->redirect(). How could this affect this behaviour?

Comment: After using $this->forward() instead of $this->redirect() the problem is solved. Thank you very much for your tips.

Comment: You might as well delete this question as I doubt it is going to help anyone else in the future.